# Validating a Dialog EditText using .contains and \\W

Tags: android, android-edittext, contains

I have an `onTextChangedListener` which watches an EditText to see if it contains any "non-word" characters like so;

```
input.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (input.getText().toString().contains("\\W")) {
                input.setError("Error");
            }
            else{

            }

        }});
```

However my code does not seem to recognise `("\\W")` as non-word characters. I have used it to check other EditTexts but in those instances it just replaces any non-word characters without prompting which works fine;

```
String locvalidated = textLocation.getText().toString().replaceAll("\\W", "-");
```

It would seem I cannot use `\\W` to check if an EditText contains such characters, only to replace them. Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`String.contains()` does not check with regular expressions. So in your case, you are just checking for the `String` `"\W"`.
It does a simple (Sub-)String compare.

A workaround is

```
String s = input.getText().toString();
boolean hasNonWord = !s.equals(s.replaceAll("\\W", "x"));
```

So, in your case:

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    String s = input.getText().toString();
    if (!s.equals(s.replaceAll("\\W", "x"))) {
        input.setError("Error");
    } else {
        input.setError(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Cheers, ideally I would like to use `setError` in this instance but it would seem I may need to resort to doing a `replaceAll` on the "invalid" characters as you described.

Comment: You can use `setError()`. My answer is just a workaround for your `String.contains("\\W")` thing.

Comment: Sorry I'm being daft. Got it now